# Python import over sub and parent folders

Tags: python, import, sys.path

I'm trying to change and use the following github project: https://github.com/flesniak/python-prodj-link/tree/2709ac77170ff13f9441ea65020e4553475c27c0

But right at the start, the imports fail.

```
ProLinkTest
├── Main.py
└── prodj
    └── core
        ├──prodj.py
        └──clientlist.py
```

In the `main.py` I'm importing:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("/home/pi/Documents/Python/ProLinkTest/prodj")
...
from prodj.core.prodj import ProDj
```

So far so good, but within the `prodj.py` I get the error:

```
    from prodj.core.clientlist import ClientList
ImportError: No module named core.clientlist
```

Line:

```
from prodj.core.clientlist import ClientList
from prodj.core.vcdj import Vcdj
from prodj.data.dataprovider import DataProvider
```

Somehow I doubt that the github repository is wrong and something is wrong with my imports. Do I need to add another `sys.path`?
Br
Tobi

Comment: is the \_\_init\_\_.py inside the proj & core directories? If Main.py is in the same directory as the proj directory, you shouldn't have to use sys.path.append

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to say. An __ini__.py is in each folder